# XSLT position of preceeding sibling with a condition

Tags: xslt, select, position, conditional-statements, xslt-1.0

I would need to understand how I can get the position of a parallel element with similar value in a sub-element selected with XSL.  I have item lines listed with certain reference as sub-element and then I have sub-item lines, which should be linked into item-lines based on the sub-element value. Sub-item lines should indicate the position of item-lines with similar reference

I have tried several different preceeding approaches with different conditions in brackets [ ] , but so far without luck. I can use only xslt 1.0

I have xml with structure like this:

```
<goods>
    <item>
        <ref>a</ref>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ref>b</ref>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ref>c</ref>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ref>d</ref>
    </item>
    <subitem>
        <subref>c</subref>
    </subitem>
    <subitem>
        <subref>a</subref>
    </subitem>
</goods>
```

and my xsl (1.0) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="Line"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Line">
        <xsl:for-each select="goods/item">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ref"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="goods/subitem">
            <xsl:text>0;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="subref"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            here would be some kind of conditional preceeding select needed
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output would be:

```
1;a
2;b
3;c
4;d
0;c;3
0;a;1
```

where 2 last lines are sub-items and the last number should tell me the position of item-element, where the same reference is. In example reference 'c' is inside item element with position 3 (third item-element has 'c' in sub-element 'ref') so subitem with subref value 'c' should be linked to item position 3 in example.

Same would go with each subitem lines: all with subitem/subref = a should have position 1, all with 'b' position 2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="ref" />

<xsl:template match="/goods">
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ref"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="subitem">
        <xsl:text>0;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="subref"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('item', subref)/preceding-sibling::item) +1" />
        <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes that every `subref` has a corresponding `item` with matching `ref` value.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot for superfast reply! Didn't understand to use key here...